# ClassCastException error, dont know why it occurs

Tags: java, android, android-listview, classcastexception

I m working with `BaseAdapter` class and i get an `ClassCastException` error in `getView` method when i try to cast my viewHolder class.

Here is my code:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            NoteItem noteItem = list.get(position);
            TextView tv;
            LinearLayout ll;
            if(convertView == null){
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_listitem_note, null);
                ll = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.llNote);
                tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvNoteItem);
                convertView.setTag(new NoteItemViewHolder(tv, ll));
                ll.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){...});
            }else{
                NoteItemViewHolder viewHolder = (NoteItemViewHolder) convertView.getTag(); //ClassCastException error here
                ll = viewHolder.getLl();
                tv = viewHolder.getName();
            }
            tv.setText(noteItem.getName());
            ll.setTag(noteItem);
            ...
            return convertView;
        }  

private class NoteItemViewHolder{

    TextView name;
    LinearLayout ll;

    public NoteItemViewHolder(TextView name, LinearLayout ll){
        this.name = name;
        this.ll = ll;
    }

    public TextView getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public LinearLayout getLl(){
        return ll;
    }       
}
```

LogCat:

```
04-16 14:10:04.979: E/AndroidRuntime(23879): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-16 14:10:04.979: E/AndroidRuntime(23879): java.lang.ClassCastException: com.calllogimprovementtools.ainius.CallLogView$NoteItem
04-16 14:10:04.979: E/AndroidRuntime(23879):    at com.calllogimprovementtools.ainius.CallLogView$MyNoteAdapter.getView(CallLogView.java:300)
04-16 14:10:04.979: E/AndroidRuntime(23879):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1409)
04-16 14:10:04.979: E/AndroidRuntime(23879):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1745)
04-16 14:10:04.979: E/AndroidRuntime(23879):    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:670)
04-16 14:10:04.979: E/AndroidRuntime(23879):    at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:641)
04-16 14:10:04.979: E/AndroidRuntime(23879):    at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:3407)
04-16 14:10:04.979: E/AndroidRuntime(23879):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:2237)
04-16 14:10:04.979: E/AndroidRuntime(23879):    at android.widget.ListView.onTouchEvent(ListView.java:3446)
04-16 14:10:04.979: E/AndroidRuntime(23879):    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3885)
04-16 14:10:04.979: E/AndroidRuntime(23879):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:903)
04-16 14:10:04.979: E/AndroidRuntime(23879):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
04-16 14:10:04.979: E/AndroidRuntime(23879):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
04-16 14:10:04.979: E/AndroidRuntime(23879):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
04-16 14:10:04.979: E/AndroidRuntime(23879):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
04-16 14:10:04.979: E/AndroidRuntime(23879):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
04-16 14:10:04.979: E/AndroidRuntime(23879):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
04-16 14:10:04.979: E/AndroidRuntime(23879):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
04-16 14:10:04.979: E/AndroidRuntime(23879):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1703)
04-16 14:10:04.979: E/AndroidRuntime(23879):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1133)
04-16 14:10:04.979: E/AndroidRuntime(23879):    at android.app.Dialog.dispatchTouchEvent(Dialog.java:642)
04-16 14:10:04.979: E/AndroidRuntime(23879):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1687)
04-16 14:10:04.979: E/AndroidRuntime(23879):    at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRoot.java:2196)
04-16 14:10:04.979: E/AndroidRuntime(23879):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1880)
04-16 14:10:04.979: E/AndroidRuntime(23879):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-16 14:10:04.979: E/AndroidRuntime(23879):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-16 14:10:04.979: E/AndroidRuntime(23879):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3729)
04-16 14:10:04.979: E/AndroidRuntime(23879):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-16 14:10:04.979: E/AndroidRuntime(23879):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-16 14:10:04.979: E/AndroidRuntime(23879):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:874)
04-16 14:10:04.979: E/AndroidRuntime(23879):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:632)
04-16 14:10:04.979: E/AndroidRuntime(23879):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Dont get why this error occurs, please help.

Comment: Can you post your logcat trace? Therein your answer lies...

Comment: try to clean up the project

Comment: First: No inheritance tree from your class is visible. Second: marking the Holder class as private so this class is not visible for other classes.

Comment: Post the full error message, both here and any time you ask about an error on SO.  Java error messages usually have good information in them, like what class it is trying to cast that it cannot.

Comment: Tried clean up, tried making holder class public and tried some suggestion below, but still error occurs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the error. The problem was that i was settings different tags to convertView ant to ll (linearlayout) which was the same view, so when the `convertView!=null` the `getTag()` returned `NoteItem` item.

Answer (score 0):

**getView** method should Like below and Also Check Your Control Like LinearLayout is bind with R.id.yourLinearID

```
  public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ViewHolder holder;
        if(view == null)
        {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.checkin_item, null);
            holder =  new ViewHolder();

            holder.iconImage = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.chkin_item_iv);
            holder.placeName = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.chkin_item_tv_name);

            view.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
        }

// here need to Bind Require Control      
holder.placeName.setText(googleSetGetArray.getGoogleSetGets().get(position).getName());

        return view;
    }

    class ViewHolder
    {
        ImageView iconImage;
        TextView placeName;         
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder2;
    View hView = convertView;

    if (convertView == null) {
        holder2 = new ViewHolder();
        hView.setTag(holder2);
    } else {
        holder2 = (ViewHolder) hView.getTag();
    }
}
```